# Code only loops on last array element

Tags: c#, monogame

Please consider this code:

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
        {
            if (isTouchingDown(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
            {
                player.CanGoUp = false;
            }
            else { player.CanGoUp = true; }

            if (isTouchingUp(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
            {
                player.CanGoDown = false;
            }
            else { player.CanGoDown = true; }

            if (isTouchingRight(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
            {
                player.CanGoLeft = false;
            }
            else { player.CanGoLeft = true; }

            if (isTouchingLeft(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
            {
                player.CanGoRight = false;
            }
            else { player.CanGoRight = true; }

        }


        player.Update();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("rect1.Top:" + gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[0].Top), new Vector2(10, 10), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("rect1.Bottom:" + gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[0].Bottom), new Vector2(10, 25), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("rect1.Left:" + gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[0].Left), new Vector2(10, 40), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("rect1.Right: " + gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[0].Right), new Vector2(10, 55), Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("rect2.Top:" + gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[1].Top), new Vector2(170, 10), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("rect2.Bottom:" + gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[1].Bottom), new Vector2(170, 25), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("rect2.Left:" + gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[1].Left), new Vector2(170, 40), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("rect2.Right:" + gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[1].Right), new Vector2(170, 55), Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("player.Top:" + player.playerRectangle.Top), new Vector2(330, 10), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("player.Bottom:" + player.playerRectangle.Bottom), new Vector2(330, 25), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("player.Left:" + player.playerRectangle.Left), new Vector2(330, 40), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ("player.Right:" + player.playerRectangle.Right), new Vector2(330, 55), Color.Black);
        gameObject.Draw(spriteBatch);

        Texture2D t = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        t.SetData<Color>(new Color[] { Color.Yellow });

        spriteBatch.Draw(t, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[0], Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(t, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[1], Color.White);

        player.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

so basically, I have a player, and I have an object.

Each object has his normal rectangle (area of texture that is for drawing)
and collision rectangle (or group of rectangle).

In this example I have an object that is a tree, so I need 2 rectangles in my collision rectangle group. One rectangle will be for the trunk of the tree and one rectangle will be for branches of the tree.

Anyways everything works, as you can see I am able to see information of all three rectangles (player rect, and 2 rectangles of collison group of a tree) and I filled 2 collision rectangles of the tree to see them in game.

Now the thing is that when my **for** loop in **Update()**
looks like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 1; ++x) //rest of that for loop up here
```

then collision stuff is only being checked for 1st collision rect of tree but not the second (and thats clear to me, because x is always 0)

**BUT**

if my for loop loks like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x) //rest of that for loop here
```

then only 2nd rectangle of my tree collision group is being chacked, and 1st rectangle not... Why is 1st not being chacked here :/// ?

Answer (score 1):

The result of your last loop is what is left because you do not combine your booleans but set then absolute. These:

```
if (isTouchingDown(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
    player.CanGoUp = false;
else { player.CanGoUp = true; }

if (isTouchingUp(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
    player.CanGoDown = false;
else { player.CanGoDown = true; }

if (isTouchingRight(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
    player.CanGoLeft = false;
else { player.CanGoLeft = true; }

if (isTouchingLeft(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
    player.CanGoRight = false;
else { player.CanGoRight = true; }
```

should be:

```
if (isTouchingDown(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
    player.CanGoUp = false;
else { player.CanGoUp &= true; } // == player.CanGoUp = Player.CanGoUp && true
                  // ^^^^              if false to begin with, will stay false

if (isTouchingUp(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
    player.CanGoDown = false;
else { player.CanGoDown &= true; }  // same here and below

if (isTouchingRight(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
    player.CanGoLeft = false;
else { player.CanGoLeft &= true; }

if (isTouchingLeft(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
    player.CanGoRight = false;
else { player.CanGoRight &= true; }
```

should be "addiditive" so if the first `x` set something to false you can not overwrite it on the 2nd `x` with true again.

For his to work you have to start out with:

```
player.CanGoUp = true;
player.CanGoDown = true; 
player.CanGoLeft = true; 
player.CanGoRight = true;
```

before your `for` loop.

If all start up as true - you might as well drop the `else` fully:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        Exit();

    player.CanGoUp = true;
    player.CanGoDown = true; 
    player.CanGoLeft = true; 
    player.CanGoRight = true;

    for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
    {
        if (isTouchingDown(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
            player.CanGoUp = false;

        if (isTouchingUp(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
            player.CanGoDown = false;

        if (isTouchingRight(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
            player.CanGoLeft = false;

        if (isTouchingLeft(player.playerRectangle, gameObject.CollisionShape.rectangles[x]))
            player.CanGoRight = false;
    } 

    player.Update();

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```